# How to get the intersection of 2 mysql queries?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

Suppose I have a MySQL table which looks like this:

[image]

Each job in the table contains 3 tasks.

How can I get all the `JobId`s whose `taskA` is in `Done` state and `taskB` is in `New` state?

In my case, I want a query which returns `qwert`, and `zxcv`.

I've come up with this query:

```
select JobId from MyTable where TaskSeq=0 and TaskState='Done'
intersect
select JobId from MyTable where TaskSeq=1 and TaskState='New';
```

but my version of MySQL doesn't support the [intercept](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/intersect.php) operator.

My ultimate goal is to write the query in [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/). But I think I should know the MySQL query first so that I can create a sequlize query.

And I also wish that the sequlize query can be done in 1 function instead of multiple functions concatenated with `then`.

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d55d09/2) to help you try the table.

Comment: can you do a `union all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a join:

```
select mt.JobId 
from   MyTable mt
         join MyTable mt2 on mt2.JobId = mt.JobId
where  mt.TaskSeq = 0 and mt.TaskState = 'Done' and mt2.TaskSeq = 1 and mt2.TaskState = 'New'
```

Here's an attempt at Sequelize on this query, however this is a guess. Hopefully it gives you something to work with:

```
MyTable.findAll({
    attributes: ['JobId', 'TaskSeq', 'TaskState'],
    include: [{
        model: MyTable,
        attributes: ['JobId', 'TaskSeq', 'TaskState'],
        where: { 
            JobId: Sequelize.col('MyTable.JobId'),
            TaskSeq: 1,
            TaskState: 'New'
        }
    }],
    where {
        TaskSeq: 0,
        TaskState: 'Done'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. But I need to write it in sequelize. Do you know how to implement it?

Comment: I've updated the question with a guess at the sequelize.